# how to enable fullscreen mode in flutter webview

Tags: flutter, webview, flutterwebviewplugin

I have my WebView where I go to Youtube and if the user touches on the Fullscreen button I want to rotate my device to landscape mode. Has anyone been faced this? Can anyone help me with how it enables!

here is my code!

```
   class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  const Home({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  final Completer<WebViewController> _controller =
  Completer<WebViewController>();


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const SafeArea(
        child: Scaffold(
      body:Center(
        child: WebView(
            initialUrl: 'https://youtube.com/',
            javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
           
        ),
      )


    ));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes thats possible but for that you have to do something like this

1-clone the webview which you are going to use
2- put that dependency locally in your project
3- now go to the dependencies lib file and remove safe area from the root screen

note: make sure you first removed the dependency from your yaml file and then add it locally so that dat pub will not get confused

Comment: can you give me any example of this how can I add it locally ?